# Acessar atributos e métodos de classe instanciada em outra classe

Tags: php

Diante da estrutura abaixo:

- class View
- class Controller

  - new View()
- class controllerUsuario extends Controller

  - public $usuario;

como acesso `$usuario` a partir da "View"?

Comment: crie um namespace e dentro da view `use nomeNameSpace`

Comment: Boa Rafael, resolvi com namespace. Deu certo, valew!

Comment: Publiquei como resposta, por favor marque como resolvida para que outros usuários possam encontrar esta solução.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `namespace` para usar classes em outros arquivos.

```
use RaizDaPasta\pastaDaClasse\Classe;
```

Dentro de seu arquivo onde você fizer o `use` instancie um novo objeto e use a função que quiser

Comment: Pra mim deu certo Rafael, vlw!

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi ao certo o que deseja fazer, mas acredito que deve ser algo parecido com isso:

```
<?php

class Apresentar
{
    public function __construct(ControllerUsuario $usuario)
    {
        echo $usuario->getUsuario();
    }
}

class ControllerUsuario
{
    private $usuario = 'Fábio';

    public function getUsuario()
    {
        return $this->usuario;
    }
}

new Apresentar(new ControllerUsuario);
```